# Looking for due-date (start/end date) management

Tags: jira

In JIRA we usually arrange work under `EPICs`, which then either have tasks directly under them or have `stories` and then tasks (the usual hierarchy). We assign start and end dates during the planning and then we know the entire duration of that `EPIC` (the latest end date is the date of delivery).

Sometimes we need to inject tasks in between, or if we realise that some work took longer, we need to change the start and end dates of some of the remaining tasks that that developer was going to do (as they have spent more time on some other prior task).

So say task-2 under some EPIC took 3 days more. Is there a way in JIRA where we can bulk select tasks-4,5,8,9 (assuming these were the ones that a particular developer was going to undertake) and give it a delta of +3 - i.e., shift their respective start and end dates by +3 (or -2 in case of negative delta etc.) ? Then if this is reflected immediately in Gantt view, it'll be even more awesome.

PS: Pls note that we don't want to create links to the tasks as start and end dates of different tasks might overlap (e.g. when you push it to review you can actually start the next task). Links would mean task-4 starts strictly after task-2's end-date which is not what we want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a self transitions for every status of the task workflow, this transition has a screen to read Delta which is a numeric customfield defined for the task. In the transition´s postfunction you use this value to shift the dates.

Then you can use a bulk transition operation to shift all your task´s start and end dates.